# Securely Change Credit Amount

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Okay I have a basic task that I want to complete and I could do it if this site wasnt going be live but since it is I am going want it to be secure and my current method needs to be better

What I want is to change how many credits a user has so another words I have it where once they click the submit button it runs a php script and just simple pull that data under there account for Credits take that number (int) and subtract 1

But I am using this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UsersList WHERE Credits='$CurrentCredits'");
```

and then I would simply

```
  $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=;host=', aooza, 'Password');

     $insert = 'INSERT INTO `LIST` (`Credits`) VALUES (:NewCreditCount)';

    $statement = $db->prepare($insert);
    $statement->bindParam(':Credit', $_SESSION['Credit'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();
```

But of course this wont work because my main issue is that it is just enters the new credit count on a new row so there is no user and well I dont know a better way to say that

How do I make it where It changes it for that row rather then just abroad

Update code

```
$Credits = $_SESSION['Credits'];

 $update= 'UPDATE `PingPalooza` SET `Credits` = `Credits` - 1 WHERE `Email` = :Email LIMIT 1';

 $_SESSION['Credits']=$Credits;

 $statement = $db->prepare($update);
 $statement->bindParam(':Credits', $_SESSION['Credits'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $statement->bindParam(':Email', $_SESSION['Email']);
 $statement->execute();
```

Obviously this isn't exactly what you gave me but I added the two variable things just to try and get it to work myself lol
lol always keep trying

Comment: Wouldn't you just want an 'UPDATE' query instead of 'INSERT'? Or have I read your question wrong?

Comment: you may see the syntax for update on this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `UPDATE` query to modify an existing row:

```
$update= 'UPDATE `LIST` SET `Credits` = `Credits` - 1 WHERE `UserId` = :UserId LIMIT 1';

$statement = $db->prepare($update);

// you don'e need this line below if you are doing the subtraction in the query (like above)
//$statement->bindParam(':Credit', $_SESSION['Credit'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(':UserId', $_SESSION['UserId']);
$statement->execute();
```

Assuming your target UserId is in `$_SESSION['UserId']` and your field in the table is `UserId`.

Comment: Can you help at all I cant seem to get this to work I dont doubt that it should work I just think that I messed it up some how lol

Comment: @bushman update the question with your new code that isn't working. It's too hard to read in the comments.

Comment: @bushman run this query direct on the DB using phpMyAdmin for example, and change the email address: `UPDATE PingPalooza SET Credits = Credits - 1 WHERE Email = 'abc@abc.com' LIMIT 1`. This will test the tablenames/field names are all correct.

Comment: This is the error im getting now

Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /home/content/34/9587634/html/Domain.Com/SubtractCredit.php on line 15

Comment: @bushman take out the binParam `Credit` line - see my edit. You don't need that line because you're doing the subtraction in the query.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me and putting up with my noob questions your awesome and that got it to work your the best.

Comment: @bushman no problem. Don't be afraid to post questions if you're having trouble, even if you think it's an easy fix :)

Comment: Thanks once again and on that topic lol how would I get this to update the session with the new value I did this but didnt seem to work
$_SESSION['Credits'] = $Credits

Comment: It would be simply: `$_SESSION['Credits']--;` or `$_SESSION['Credits'] = $_SESSION['Credits'] - 1;`.